# How to extract the element(s) that contains some known text

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm using Watir-Webdriver.

I know there is specific text on a page, which is: "First Name is required"

`browser.text.include("First Name is required")` returns `true` which is good.

Using Watir-Webdriver is there some method that I can append to the end of `browser.text.include("First Name is required")` that will return the css/html that houses that specific text?

An inspect element on this textfield returns:

```
<h3 class="split-sm"></h3>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-container input-left-half round">
        <div class="validate status-invalid"></div>
        <input id="member_first_name" type="text" name="member_first_name"></input>
        <label class="error" for="member_first_name">
            <span class="label-norm">
                First Name
            </span>
            <span id="member_first_name-error" class="label-error">
                is required
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you consider `xpath`?

Comment: What do you mean by "css/html?" The text you want is split into two separate span elements. Do you want to get a Watir::Element object for one of those, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Which element would you want to get back? For example, the text is included in `<div class="input-group">`, `<div class="input-container input-left-half round">`, `<label class="error" for="member_first_name">` and any ancestor elements such as `<body>`. The most ancestor element would be easy to do, but I am guessing you want the closest ancestor - the `label`?

Comment: I guess I'd want the closest possible element(s) that contain that text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find any element that contains a specific text, you can use the `element` method with a `:text` locator:

```
browser.element(:text => 'First Name is required')
```

However, by default, Watir will return the first element that matches. Given that we are searching the entire DOM for any element type, this will always be the `html` element:

```
browser.element(:text => 'First Name is required').tag_name
#=> "html"
```

If you know more details about the element you are looking for, you could combine it with the `:text` locator and get that specific element. For example, if you know it will always be a `label` element with class "error", you could do:

```
browser.label(:class => 'error', :text => 'First Name is required').html
#=> <label class="error" for="member_first_name">
#=>   <span class="label-norm">
#=>     First Name
#=>   </span>
#=>   <span id="member_first_name-error" class="label-error">
#=>     is required
#=>   </span>
#=> </label>
```

If you cannot create a more specific locator, you could use the `elements` method (note the pluralization) to find *all* elements that include the specific text. The last element in the collection will be the closest possible element that includes the text:

```
browser.elements(:text => 'First Name is required').last.html
#=> <label class="error" for="member_first_name">
#=>   <span class="label-norm">
#=>     First Name
#=>   </span>
#=>   <span id="member_first_name-error" class="label-error">
#=>     is required
#=>   </span>
#=> </label>
```

Comment: Although, I didn't accomplish what I was trying to do, your answer provided me with some useful tips, thanks!